# Global.asax And Unhandled Exceptions

Tags: asp.net

I've got some code that is logging unhandled exceptions in the global.asax. Whenever an error occurs I get the error I write to the eventlog correctly and then the same exception written again as unhandled. Have missed something simple?

Comment: "and then the same exception written again as unhandled. " << Can you clarify what you mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you log the exception, you should call

```
Server.ClearError();
```

If you want the exception to be treated as "Handled".

Remember this isn't a normal catch block and special rules apply.